# Data Loss Event ID 25 "The shadow copies on Volume E: were deleted because shadow copy storage could not grow in time."

Tags: windows, vss, shadow-copies

I am experiencing loss of shadow copies, and this is accompanied by eventId 25:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Volsnap
Date:          8/27/2020 6:41:11 PM
Event ID:      25
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      name.example.com
Description:
The shadow copies of volume D: were deleted because the shadow copy storage could not grow in time.  Consider reducing the IO load on the system or choose a shadow copy storage volume that is not being shadow copied.
```

[This article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1886c270-fc4c-41b5-b25f-3a8d52a4a8a7/data-loss-event-id-25-quotthe-shadow-copies-on-volume-e-were-deleted-because-shadow-copy-storage) explains that we can use a 3rd party tool, [AlphaVSS](https://alphavss.alphaleonis.com/index.html) to override [VSS_PROTECTION_LEVEL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/vsmgmt/ne-vsmgmt-vss_protection_level) so the shadow copy provider maintains shadow copies at the expense of I/O to original volume.

Unfortunately, I can't use 3rd party tools like this at my organization :(. Are there other ways to configure this setting (e.g. registry key setting)?

I spent quite some time looking for resources online, but most of them pointed me to the alphavss
library.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1886c270-fc4c-41b5-b25f-3a8d52a4a8a7/data-loss-event-id-25-quotthe-shadow-copies-on-volume-e-were-deleted-because-shadow-copy-storage?forum=windowsbackup

So here is what I have found:

1. If you run chkdsk e: /c /i it will increase the shadowstorage to the MinDiffAreaFileSize (50GB in my case). I am trying to reverse engineer what chkdsk.exe does at the very beginning of when it runs, so I can create a function that increases the shadowstorage space and skip the disk check part.

maybe this will help you, there is a post about AlphaVSS considering some issues and and this might help, otherwise you could use another drive to store the shadow copies to avoid this error.
Below you find a link to set a regkey which also might help as well.
have a look at MinDiffAreaFileSize ...

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/backup/registry-keys-for-backup-and-restore#maxshadowcopies